# Making character class with modifier symbols in Perl 6

Tags: raku

I'd like to make a user-defined character class of "vowels", which will match any literal English vowel letter (a, e, i, o, u) as well as any of these letters with any possible diacritics: ắ ḗ ú̱ å ų̄ ẹ́ etc.

This is what I've tried to do, but it doesn't work:

```perl6
> my $vowel = / <[aeiou]> <:Sk>* /
/ <[aeiou]> <:Sk>* /
> "áei" ~~ m:g/ <$vowel> /
(｢e｣ ｢i｣)
```

Comment: Have you tried [ignoremark](https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes#Ignoremark)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try use [ignoremark](https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes#Ignoremark):

> The :ignoremark or :m adverb instructs the regex engine to only
>   compare base characters, and ignore additional marks such as combining
>   accents.

For your example:

```
my $vowel = /:m<[aeiou]>/;
.say for "áeikj" ~~ m:g/ <$vowel> /;
```

**Output**:

```
｢á｣
｢e｣
｢i｣
```

Comment: Great, thank you! The problem is that the regex doesn't look like a character class and I'm not sure I can use it a such. E.g., how can I subtract it to get `regex` for "conconants"? In simple case I can define `my $consonant = / <:L-[aeiou]> /;`.

Comment: I've tried `my $consonant = / <!before <$vowel>> <:L> /` and it seems to work, but maybe there is a more simple way?

Comment: Interesting question, could you eloborate on why you need to subtract classes (i.e. why you cannot simply use `my $cons = /:m<[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]> /`)

Comment: Because it's more universal and convenient. E.g. `ʔ` and `ʕ` are letters as well (and I use them every day), and in some cases working with my data I cannot know beforehand which other letter symbols I will encounter.

Comment: @EugeneBarsky Iirc a character class expression is run efficiently on an [NFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton) and many regex constructs mess with that so currently (maybe forever) general regex constructs are disallowed in a character class expression. So I think the `before` thing you showed is the way to go. I'm not sure if this is officially supported but in current Rakudo you can write `<!$vowel>` instead of `<!before <$vowel>>` and get the same result.

Answer (score 10):

The reason you can't match a vowel with a combining character using `/ <[aeiou]> <:Sk>* /` is that strings in Perl 6 are operated on at the grapheme level. At that level, `ų̄` is already just a single character, and `<[aeiou]>` being a character class already matches one whole character.

The right solution is, as Håkon pointed out in the other answer, to use the `ignoremark` adverb. You can put it before the regex like `rx:m/ <[aeiou]> /` or inside of it, or even turn it on and off at different points with `:m` and `:!m`.